# General Relativity and spin/helicity two massless particle

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-spin, gravitational-waves, helicity

1. I usually read that GR can be thought of as the unique theory of a massless spin-2 particle  (I think that this is the graviton).
2. I know that GR is the unique theory that has:

   - diffeomorphism invariance (active and passive diffeo and active is the peculiarity)
   - equivalence principle (the strong one I think is the one that people refer to)

Does those two last statements imply the first one?

Comment: I don't really know anything about this, but it might be interesting to look into linearized gravity.  The metric perturbation satisfies a wave equation and it's gauge transformations are Lie derivatives of the metric.

Comment: I also thought of this. But, when I am in the linearized version are the degrees of freedom conserved with resepect to the full theory?
Another interesting question is if I can define a concept of spin in general non flat manifolds... Because with linearized version, imagining a symmetric tensor propagating in flat space is simple.